# How to ping From destination A to destination B with my laptop?

Tags: ping, ethernet

How can I ping from destination A to destination B with my laptop?
(I'm sorry that I have no network knowledge..)

Explanation:

1. ECU A and ECU B is connected via eth line.
2. I can access ECU A via ping test.
   (ECU A is connected with OBD cable and I can check with ping test)
   (EX: ping X.X.X.X  is success)
3. I need to access ECU B via ECU A. So I want to check how I can ping to ECU B via ECU A with my laptop
   (EX: ping X.X.X.X to Y.Y.Y.Y )
4. If 3 step is success, I will try to access SSH to ECU B.

If this kind of trial is not right, please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

Use SSH or something to be able to access the destination A machine.
After that you can ping Destination B from A.
The same applies from B to A.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
I am using Mobaxterm to access destination A.
Is it possible to access via SSH to destination B with using Mobaxterm also ?

Comment: you can try doing telnet, might work.